Is it possible to set the tailwind "important selector" only for specific files defined in the "content" config?
I have the following tailwind.config.js that uses the important: ".custom-component".
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: ".custom-component",
  darkMode: "class",
  content: ["./config/**/*.{jsx,yml}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

The resulted classes in the output.css looks like this:
.custom-component .flex-1 { flex:1 1 0% }

However, I would like to apply the "important selector" only for some specific files defined in the "content" property. Is it possible??

Nope! Tailwind doesn't really track files to that individual level.
